# Selecting an entity with multiple child entities

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

Using Active Record/NHibernate, I'm trying to select an entity (Site) which has multiple child collections.

There is only one Site with the given siteId, yet the FindAll returns the Site 28 times; it's being duplicated due to the child collections that it's loading. How do I get it to load just the 1 Site and arrays of the child collections? I don't mind if it does 5 selects, one to grab the site and then 1 per child collection.

Here is the code:

```
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Site>()
                    .CreateAlias("TimeZone", "tz", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                    .CreateAlias("Logos", "l", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                    .CreateAlias("SiteColors", "sc", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                    .CreateAlias("ManagerUsers", "mu", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", siteId));
                var sites = FindAll(criteria);
```

I should mention that I also tried an hql approach using fetch, however fetch is not fetching! It returns only the one Site (good) but none of the child collections are eagerly loaded (bad).

```
public static Site Get(int id)
        {
            var query = new SimpleQuery<Site>(@"
                from Site s
                where s.Id = ?
                inner join fetch s.TimeZone tc
                left join fetch s.Logos l
                left join fetch s.SiteColors sc
                left join fetch s.ManagerUsers mu
            ", id);
            var results = query.Execute().ToList();
            return results.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Here is code that seems to work, using the "Future" approach:

```
public static Site Get(int id)
        { 
            var session = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder().CreateSession(typeof(Site));
            var query = session.CreateQuery("from Site s left join fetch s.Logos where s.Id = :id").SetParameter("id", id).Future<Site>();
            session.CreateQuery("from Site s left join fetch s.SiteColors where s.Id = :id2").SetParameter("id2", id).Future<Site>();
            session.CreateQuery("from Site s left join fetch s.ManagerUsers where s.Id = :id3").SetParameter("id3", id).Future<Site>();
            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

All of my data model classes inherit from a SimpleModel class, which I've added Equals and GetHashCode methods to:

```
public abstract class SimpleModel
    {
        protected SimpleModel()
        {
            DateCreated = DateTimeAccess.Now;
        }

        [PrimaryKey]
        [DocumentId]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        [Property]
        public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is SimpleModel)
            {
                return Id.Equals(((SimpleModel)obj).Id);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `SetResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntity)` on your criteria. It will collapse those duplicate `Site` instances to a single instance.

For more information, see this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/9919812230702ccc

Comment: Thanks @Mauricio. Which method is a better practice, using SetResultTransformer or creating a new session and using the Future method to join multiple queries?

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work, it forces there to only be one root entity, which is great, however it duplicates the child entities. For instance one of my child collections is supposed to have 21 objects, instead it now has 315.

Comment: @Justin: make sure you have properly implemented GetHashCode() and Equals()

Comment: @Mauricio: Could you explain a little more on this or provide me with a link? The only reason I have ever implemented GetHashCode() and Equals() was when I had a composite primary key, and that's not the case here.

Comment: @Justin: it's not just for composite PKs. Start here: http://www.derickbailey.com/2008/03/24/NHibernateBestPracticesALWAYSOverrideEqualsAndGetHashCode.aspx

Comment: @Mauricio: Thanks, but I tried adding GetHashCode and Equals methods to my base SimpleModel class (see edit above), yet it still returns duplicate child  collections.